# UITableView. Как изменить значения для ключа в NSDictionary?

Tags: xcode, ios

```
NSDictionary *one = @{@"number": [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                      @"name": @"Kiew",
                      @"URL":[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiev"]};

NSDictionary *two = @{@"number": [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                      @"name": @"Cherkassy",
                      @"URL":[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B"]};

NSDictionary *three = @{@"number": [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                        @"name": @"Moskow",
                        @"URL":[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow"]};

NSDictionary *four = @{@"number" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],
                       @"name" : @"Minsk",
                       @"URL" : [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA"]};

data3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:one,two,three,four, nil];
```

Я из массива datа3 создаю таблицу в тайтл идет ключ name а в десрипшин тайтл number, по нажатию на ячейку открываю ссылку. Это все работает, не могу никак понять как сделать:
"кнопку, по нажатию на которую все поля-значения (NSNumber) должны получить новое случайное значение"

кнопку я добавил и метод обновления таблицы тоже.

Подскажите как изменить значения для ключа number в NSDictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте **NSMutableDictionary**

```
NSMutableDictionary * myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[myDictionary setObject:@"Ira" forKey:@"name"];
```